# How to pass function/closure without calling it?

Tags: javascript, react-native, closures

I'm trying to set a state which happens to be a function in react-native like this:

```
...
    setSendFunction(function () {
        console.log('HELLO');
    });
```

But everytime this line, runs, "HELLO" is printed, which I do not want. I just want this anonymous function to be stored somewhere without running it.

Comment: React `setState` functions take a callback. You'll want `setSendFunction(oldSendFunction => function() { … })`

Comment: thank you, would you mind making an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: @user2864740 That tripped me up too initially, but Bergi's right. The issue is that state setters, when passed functions, invoke the functions (with the prior state value as the argument). The code, even without `sendFunction()` anywhere, will log HELLO.

Comment: @user2864740 Bergi's doesn't *call* the function that logs `HELLO`, it *returns* a function that calls `HELLO` - the value returned from a state setter callback will then be the new state.

Comment: Ah, too late.. *sigh*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bergi said, you want to do something like

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
//here func() will give you the value of 5
  const [func, setFunc] = useState(() => () => 5);

  const handleClick = (num) => {
// after this, func() will provide new value, which is num
    setFunc((prevState) => () => prevState() + num);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{func()} </h2>
      <button onClick={(e) => handleClick(10)}> Change State</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```